# about sizeof Class in C++

Tags: c++, sizeof

Output is 1,4,8,why c = 8,is not 1+4.If nothing in Base, sizeof(Base) = 1.and sizeof(A) = 1.In my understanding sizeof(A) is 4.why the result shows 1.

````
```
class Base{};
class A{
    Base a;
};
class B{
    int b;
    
};
class C{
    Base a;
    int b;
    
};

int main()
{
    int a = sizeof(A);//1
    int b = sizeof(B);//4
    int c = sizeof(C);//8
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<b<<endl;
    cout<<c<<endl;
    return 0;
    
}```
````

Comment: *In my understanding sizeof(A) is 4?*  Why do you have that understanding?

Comment: How big is Base?

Comment: Compilers may add padding between members and at the end of a struct/class. Also, what's the size of a `int` on your platform?

Comment: Class must have a non-zero size (thus min 1). But a class does not need to take up any space in another object if it does not need to.